# Issues with handling SSL certiicates on Chrome, IE and Opera

Tags: selenium, ssl, selenium-chromedriver, operadriver

As the title says it, I'm struggling with handling the SSL certificates in Chrome, IE and Opera browsers.
What I'm doing:

```
ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();
opt.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.AcceptSslCertificates, true);

IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(opt);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://localhost");
```

What I'm getting:

```
Result StackTrace:  
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeOptions options)
   at ...  (project name and path here)
Result Message: Initialization method <Project and test method name here> threw exception. System.InvalidOperationException: System.InvalidOperationException: unknown error: cannot parse capability: chromeOptions
from unknown error: unrecognized chrome option: acceptSslCerts
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64).
```

Similarly, I'm getting the same thing for Opera browser by using `OperaOptions` and `OperaDriver` classes:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: unknown error: cannot parse capability: operaOptions
from unknown error: unrecognized chrome option: acceptSslCerts
```

And for Internet Explorer browser, by using `InternetExplorerOptions` and `InternetExplorerDriver` classes, I'm not getting any errors, but the SSL Certificate is not handled properly.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Few things I am assuming you've already set chromedriver executable property. I would suggest you to try this out as below:

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capability.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
driver = new ChromeDriver(capability);
```